# ECDH + JWE encryption using nimbus-jose and Java 6

Tags: java, encryption, jwt, jwe, nimbus-jose-jwt

I have a problem and I would like to know if you can help me.

I need to create an encrypted JWE with elliptic curve.

i am using

jre 1.6.0, nimbus-jose-jwt-8.20-jdk6.jar ,bcprov-jdk15to18-166.jar.

I have created a keystore and a key pair with the EC algorithm and elliptic curve P-512. If I sign the JWT with the private key and then I try to validate it with the public key everything works fine, but apart from signing I need to encrypt to make a JWE in which the payload is not seen.

When trying to encrypt the JWE with the public key it throws the following Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Objects
at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.KeyUse.hashCode(KeyUse.java:121)
at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.KeyUseAndOpsConsistency.<clinit>(KeyUseAndOpsConsistency.java:43)
at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK.<init>(JWK.java:197)
at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.ECKey.<init>(ECKey.java:706)
at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.ECKey$Builder.build(ECKey.java:571)
at com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.ECDHEncrypter.encrypt(ECDHEncrypter.java:217)
at com.nimbusds.jose.JWEObject.encrypt(JWEObject.java:370)
at pruebasJwt.inicioJwt.main(inicioJwt.java:373)
```

this is the code that I use to encrypt:

```
        //encriptar token
        ECPublicKey publicKey = (ECPublicKey) certificadoBean.getPublicKey();
        Payload payload = new Payload(signedJWT2);
        JWEObject jwe = new JWEObject(jweHeader, payload);                              
        jwe.encrypt(new ECDHEncrypter(publicKey)); //**This is where the exception occurs**
        String jweString = jwe.serialize();
        
        String tokenJwt = signedJWT2.serialize();
        System.err.println(tokenJwt);
```

I have the libraries well defined in the eclipe classpath.

Although my requirements is JWE encrypted with an elliptic curve, I have created a test certificate RSA and in this way I have been able to generate an encrypted JWE with said certificate without problems.

I have also used a very simple example that they put on the https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jws-with-ec-signature page and it doesn't work for me either. When creating the key pair I get the same exception.

```
public class JweEC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("############ INICIO JWE FIRMADO CON CERTIFICADO CURVA ELIPTICA ##############");
        System.out.println("soporta ES512" + JCASupport.isSupported(JWSAlgorithm.ES512));
        
        //Proveedor de criptografica
        Provider bc = BouncyCastleProviderSingleton.getInstance();
        Security.addProvider(bc);
        System.out.println("soporta ES512" + JCASupport.isSupported(JWSAlgorithm.ES512));
        try {
            
            ECKey ecJWK = new ECKeyGenerator(Curve.P_521)
                    .generate(); **This is where the exception occurs**
                ECKey ecPublicJWK = ecJWK.toPublicJWK();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

}
```

The NoClassDefFoundError Exception indicates that the class loader responsible for dynamic class loading cannot find the .class file for the class you are trying to use, but as I said before all my libraries are well included in the classpath.

Could it be that I am missing some liberia to include? I don't know, I'm lost with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response from connect2id telling me that it was a problem as Luke said, there are things encoded with Java 7 and this case was one of them.
In the end trying other versions with nimbus-jose-jwt-6.8-jdk6.jar finally everything works as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that nimbus-jose-jwt-8.20-jdk6.jar does not support being run on Java 6, despite the appearance of 'jdk6' in its name.

You are getting the error you are seeing because the `hashCode()` method of the [KeyUse](https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/src/master/src/main/java/com/nimbusds/jose/jwk/KeyUse.java) class uses a method in the [`java.util.Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) utility class, and this class is only available from Java 7 onwards.

I would **strongly** recommend upgrading from Java 6, to Java 8 at least.  Doing so would certainly get around this problem.  However, if you are stuck with Java 6, you will have to [get in contact with Connect2Id](https://connect2id.com/contact) and ask them for support.

Comment: Thanks for responding Luke.  t's certainly not a tasteful dish to work with Java6 but I can't upgrade to Java 8, it's all problems with Java 6.

I have also thought the same thing you say that nimbus-jose-jwt-8.20-jdk6.jar is not completely compatible with Java 6.

I had already contacted Connet2id. I hope they give me some kind of solution, if so, I will publish it in this same post in case another person can find myself in the same situation.